# Fourier Series - working out relationship between $C_n$ and $A_n,B_n$

Tags: fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

[textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pvkb.png)

Hi I was reading my textbook, but I needed some clarity on the last step of the working out, how does the equation simplify from :

$x(t) = c_o + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \exp(j n \omega t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{-n} \exp(-j n \omega t) $

TO

$x(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_1 \exp(j n \omega t)$

Comment: Swap $n$ with $-n$, perhaps.

Comment: There is a typo in your last formula : $c_1$ should be $c_n$...

Comment: The last formula should be from -inf to inf

Comment: The [exponential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form) of a Fourier series is
$$x(t)=
\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=-N}^N c_n\, e^{j n \omega t}\right)$$ (where $j=i$ and $\omega=\frac{2 \pi}{P}$) which can be evaluated as
$$x(t)=c_0+
\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N c_n\, e^{j n \omega t}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N c_{-n}\, e^{-j n \omega t}\right)$$
or as
$$x(t)=c_0+
\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left(c_n\, e^{j n \omega t}+c_{-n}\, e^{-j n \omega t}\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

There are three parts, the first from -inf to -1, the second is 0, and the third from 1 to inf. then the total addition is from -inf to inf.

For the first part you could replace new(n) <- -old(n)

---

$$ x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c_n e^{nwt j}+c_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e^{nwt j} $$
where:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{-n} e^{-nwt j} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c_n e^{nwt j}$$

It is possible to write the three terms in a single summation:
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{nwt j} $$

[image]

Comment: Why are you allowed to convert the first summation into Cn from -infinity to -1?

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of handwriting.

Comment: @Priit The minus sign was simply moved from the sum term to the sum limit. The sum is typically evaluated over a finite number of terms as $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N c_{-n}\, e^{-j n \omega t}\right)$, so the first sum makes more sense than the second sum from this perspective.